# Laravel controller to act as proxy

Tags: php, laravel

In my situation i have a trusted Server 1 communicating with a trusted Server 2.

In need to act as a middleman to filter some kind of communications to Server 2,:

Server1 -> [Laravel] -> Server 2.

Is there a simple way inside the controller to "copy" Server1 Request (headers and content) and execute it toward server 2 other than "re-create" it ?

Comment: Using Laravel to do that looks like overkill. Why not use nginx directly? There's plenty of documentation on how to use Nginx to act as proxies

Comment: i am allowed to operate on the application, but not on the server; furthermore the filtering rules are quite complex and could rely on user permissions/further checks in db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after looking deeper, there were A LOT of possible solutions:

Laravel uses Symfony Httpfoundation component and Request.

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation;
```

The object therefore has 2 possibile ways to achieve what I was looking for

1) create a new request via the constructor

2) create it from global variables:

```
Request::createFromGlobals()
```

If using Illuminate\Request, there is also:

2b) an incapsulation of 2)

```
Request::capture()
```

3) create it from an existing Request via

```
Request::createFrom($from, $to=null)
```

and

4) create it from an existing SymfonyRequest obj

```
Request::createFromBase(SymfonyRequest $request)
```